# Creating custom dependent picklist field in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

I have a picklist field which I am fetching using wire. Now the scenario is I have to fetch all the records of the selected picklist value and show the values of one of the field in records in another picklist.

Say I have Type as one Picklist then based on Type value, I need to show the Account Names in other picklist field where Type value is the selected Type.

I have written the below code till now but when I select the Type value for the 1st time it gives me "Cannot read property of length error"  and when I select it for the 2nd time it doesn't give me any error but can't get Account Name values in the dependent picklist field

**HTML:**

```
<lightning-layout-item size="10" padding="horizontal-medium">
                    <lightning-combobox class="" options={typeValues} dropdown-alignment="auto" 
                       label="Type"
                        placeholder="--Select Type--" value={typeSelected} onchange= 
                              {handleTypeChange}
                        required>
                    </lightning-combobox>
</lightning-layout-item>
<lightning-layout-item size="5" padding="horizontal-medium">
                <lightning-combobox class="" options={accountNames} dropdown-alignment="auto" 
                                   label="Account"
                    placeholder="--Select Account--" value={accountSelected} onchange= 
                             {handleNameChange}
                    required disabled={isTypeSelected}>
                </lightning-combobox>
</lightning-layout-item>
```

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Type';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.getAccounts';

export default class TestLwcPicklist extends LightningElement {
 
@track typeValues;
@track isTypeSelected = true;
@track accountNamePicklist = [];
@track typeSelected;
@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD })
    typePicklistValues({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.typeValues = data.values;
            this.error = undefined;
        }
        if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.typeValues = undefined;
        }
    }
handleProductChange(event) {
            this.typeSelected = event.detail.value;
            this.isTypeSelected = false;
            
            this.fetchAccountNamePicklist();
        }
    
        fetchAccountNamePicklist() {
            getAccounts({ type: this.typeSelected })
                .then(result => {
                    this.account = result;
                    this.error = undefined;
                    this.account.forEach(row => {
                        let name = { label:row.Name, value:row.Name };
                        this.accountNamePicklist.push(name);
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                    this.account = undefined;
                })
                
            
    
        }
    
    get accountNames() {
            return this.accountNamePicklist;
        }
}
```

**APEX:**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Account> getAccounts(String type){
     List<Account> lstAcc = [SELECT Id, Name, Type from Account Where Type = :type]
     return lstAcc
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property account will be undefined first time, because you have misplaced the for-loop  in the below code.

```
fetchAccountNamePicklist() {
        getAccounts({ type: this.typeSelected })
            .then(result => {
                this.account = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.account = undefined;
            })

            for (var i = 0; i < this.account.length; i++) {
                this.accountNamePicklist = [...this.accountNamePicklist, { label: this.account[i].Name, value: this.account[i].Name }];
            }
    }
```

Which should be like this.

```
fetchAccountNamePicklist() {
    getAccounts({ type: this.typeSelected })
        .then(result => {
            this.account = result;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.account.length; i++) {
                this.accountNamePicklist = [...this.accountNamePicklist, { label: this.account[i].Name, value: this.account[i].Name }];
            }
            this.error = undefined;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
            this.account = undefined;
        })
    }
}
```

Also note that as you have not used the `account` property anywhere else, you don't even need to store it. You can simply generate the options right there based on the result.

Also a few other improvements you can do.

- Always use `let` instead of `var` for block-scoped variables.
- the for-loop you have used to set `accountNamePicklist` is not efficient. instead of that use the `array.map()`. Its a bad idea to clone the array, inside the for-loop. you could have used `array.push()` as well.